# Render a Component when a Angular Feature module is imported

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular Application. In my `app.module.ts` declaration I would do something like this:

## App.module (my Root Module):

```
let imports = [
     //....
];
if (!environment.production) {
   imports.push(DevToolsModule);
} 

@NgModule({
  imports: imports,
  ...
  })
```

## DevToolsModule (my Feature Module):

My separate feature module `DevToolsModule` looks like the following:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [DeveloperToolsComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  entryComponents: [DeveloperToolsComponent]
})
export class DevToolsModule {}
```

What I would do now, is the following:

When my `DevToolsModule` gets imported, I would like to show a component on my screen with some developer information. It should be automatically added, I don't want to define it anywhere in my `app.html` template.

Did anyone achieve something like that?

Thanks so much, 
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following,

```
    let developmentModules = [ 
         DevToolsModule
     ] 
     if(environment.production) {
        developmentModules = [];
        enableProdMode();
     }
     @NgModule({
       imports: [
         BrowserModule,
         ...developmentModules
       ],
       declarations: [],
       providers: [],
     })
     export class AppModule
```

The spread operator `...` allows to easily place an expanded version of an array into another array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, maybe I made it to little clear. So, i tried to update the description: 
I do have two modules, and I dont want my main module (app.module) to depend on the UI Component of my DevToolsModule. I just want to add a component to the SPA `body` if the feature module gets imported into a root module.

Answer (score 0):

When you import your feature module in root module, it will automatically be added to tree. You don't need to edit app.component.html template for that, but to demonstration, you should. 
If you can't edit app.component.html template, you can add the feature module component dynamically as @viewchild instance and ComponentFactoryResolver in app.component.ts, but I wouldn't recommend it. Instead you should define the feature module component as a decleration, then use it in template

```js
<child-component></child-component>
```

Anyway if you still find this silly, you might want checkout the article: [Dynamically add components to the DOM with Angular](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/dynamically-add-components-to-the-dom-with-angular-71b0cb535286)

Comment: I dont want to edit my template. I basically only want to add a view Component as soon as the Feature-Module gets imported to the RootModule.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically thinking of this:

```
constructor(@Optional() devToolsModule:DevToolsModule ) {
    if(devToolsModule){
       //add component to view
    }
}
```